# Django - Href not redirecting user but being loaded locally

Tags: python, html, django, url, href

I am creating a simple application in Django. I have an `<a>` element, and when the user clicks on it, I want to be able to redirect them to a new page **(classes.html)**.

I used `href="{% url 'classes' %}"`, but when the user clicks on it, nothing happens. However, I can see that the URL has been loaded because the tag at the bottom screen loads the URL.

Additionally, when I inspect the element, I see that the URL has been loaded and when I click on it, it takes me to the **classes** URL. Can someone please help me so that when the user clicks on the 
, it redirects them to the **classes** screen?

I have tried conducting a hard reload, re-doing my URLs and views, and setting up a virtual environment, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What element are you using? Is it `<a href="{% url 'classes' %}">text</a>`?

Comment: yes.
```<li class="mr-12"><a class=" text-slate-400   font-medium hover:text-white         transition ease-in-out delay-150" href="{% url 'classes' %}" data-config-id="auto-txt-2-2" style=" font-size: 18px" >Classes</a></li>```

Comment: Please add to question rendered html part for this link.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean adding html that you see on loaded page in browser (where instead of `{% url...` you see the actual link). Also `hover:text-white` is very odd css class (thought it's invalid, but probably not: escaping is strictly required in css, html may be more forgiving). Do you have custom JS on that page?

Comment: I believe that `hover:text-white` is a tailwind class, so it's 100% valid.

Comment: @jahantaila oops, haven't worked with tailwind. Checked their source - they really use colon in classes heavily. Looks kinda strange for me, but its their decision. Thanks for this information!

Comment: edit your question and add your view for classes url and template for the url that redirects to classes